# Convert from erlang:system_time() to os:timestamp()

Tags: time, erlang, erlang-otp

How can I convert erlang:system_time(), integer, to os:timestamp()  {MegaSecs, Secs, MicroSecs} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_time-1), we can convert with code below:

```
 timestamp() ->  
    ErlangSystemTime = erlang:system_time(microsecond),
    MegaSecs = ErlangSystemTime div 1000000000000,
    Secs = ErlangSystemTime div 1000000 - MegaSecs*1000000,
    MicroSecs = ErlangSystemTime rem 1000000,
    {MegaSecs, Secs, MicroSecs}
```